# Correct way to extend Angular class

Tags: javascript, angular, inheritance

I'm working on an `Angular` (6) project and I'm trying to (elegantly) extend a *Base Class* for my containers. The app is really a "web tool" rather than a traditional "web app" (i.e. it follows a sequential order, rather than allowing the user to move around pages as they please).

If the user navigates on their own, I need the rendering container to check to see that all of its dependencies have been met (i.e. have all prior stages been completed?). If they haven't, I need to bring the user back to the earliest container that has all of it's dependents met.

Basically I made a *Base Class* that runs this check on initialization and manages any necessary redirect behavior. This all works as expected, but my issue is that the base class needs the `StageGuard service` (responsible for the aforementioned dependency check and redirect) passed to it through each container's constructor.

Considering I'll probably expand upon this base class to do more things that all containers will need, the need to pass items and services (other than unique properties associated with the container like, *Stage Name*) to the base class via the `super()` call.

I'm not sure how I'd get around this, only because the issue kind of makes sense -- the *Base Class* can't use the instances of services created because it's never a standalone instance itself. That said, you can probably understand why I'm plagued by a "there has to be a better way!" sensation.

Apologies if this is classical inheritance 101 and my googling is failing me, any insight is greatly appreciated.